# Open CS5 document in Indesign CS6 without converting

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, cs5, save

I'm working the layout for a school newspaper using InDesign.  However, while the school's computers have CS5, installed, I have CS6 on my home computer.  I can access the files from home because they are stored on the school's afp server.

What I want to do is to open the CS5 document in CS6 *without converting it.*  I know about .IDML, but I don't want to use it as it'll result in confusion on my teacher's and fellow students' parts and we'd end up with multiple documents that might get edited independently, leading to even more confusion.

To reiterate, I don't want to *export* the document; I want to save it. And I only want to have one document the whole time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, ID doesn't work that way; it's not like Photoshop. If you open the CS5 document in any later version of the program, it will convert it. You don't have the option to save an earlier *InDesign* file; you can only save as an IDML.

If you don't want multiple documents, then either don't work on it in CS6, or save the IDML in CS5 immediately when you get to school so that no one else sees it.

Comment: Isn't there a Caveat in that Photoshop doesn't work that way either? Or is it just Illustrator that warns about features that got implemented differently in newer versions?

Comment: @Jongware I think it's just Illustrator which works the same way ID does. I'm pretty sure, but I won't bet the house on it, that PS is backwards- and forwards-compatible. Obviously if you're using more sophisticated filters or effects you might not be able to access it in an earlier version, but I *think* you can pretty much open and save in whatever version with abandon.